# Validate that a relative path exists or is an external URI

Tags: javascript, node.js, grunt.js

I sent a PR to a repo the other day and want to make sure I have the right idea for URI validation.

```
function validateURI(files) {
    //...
    // files can be either a string or an array of paths
    // validates the relative path exists or is an http(s) URI
    // returns a filtered list of valid paths
    // (e.g.) ["../dne.js", "//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"] => ["//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"]
    if(typeof files !== "object") files = [files]; //wrap string
    var local = grunt.file.expand(opt, files),
        remote = _.map(files, path.normalize).filter(function(path) { //for loading from cdn
            return /^((http|https):)?(\\|\/\/)/.test(path); //is http, https, or //
        });
    return _.uniq(local.concat(remote));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Very interesting,

I only have 1 snarky comment, if `files` is an array of 'paths', maybe you should call it `paths` ;)

Also, as a user of this function, I might want to override your regex so you might want to provide support for that.

Comment: Good point on the optional user validator, that could definitely be useful.